# Android ImageViewの画像の変更

Tags: android

ImageViewのsetImageResourceメソッドをつかってpopupwindowから画像を変更したいのですが、上手くいきません。
どうすればいいのでしょうか。

```
final PopupWindow mPopupWindow=new PopupWindow(Books_new.this);
final View popupView=getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.popup_icon, null);

//ポップアップウィンドウでアイコン変更

popupView.findViewById(R.id.btn_red).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v){
    ChangeToBlue(v);
  }
});

popupView.findViewById(R.id.btn_pink).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v){
    ChangeToRed(v);
  }
});

public static void ChangeToRed(View v){
  ImageView iIcon=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.view_books_icon);
  iIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.red_project);
}
public static void ChangeToBlue(View v){
  ImageView iIcon=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.view_books_icon);
  iIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.blue_project);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void ChangeToBlue(View v){
  ImageView iIcon=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.view_books_icon);
  iIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.blue_project);
}
```

この`v.findViewById()`は、引数の`View`、`R.id.btn_red`の`id`を持つ`View`の子要素に対して検索を行っています。ですので、`null`が返ってくると思います。

メソッドの`static`を外して、以下のように`Activity`または`Fragment`の`View`全体に対して検索するように修正してみてください。もしこのメソッドが`Activity`や`Fragment`以外で実装されている場合は、それぞれが管理する`View`のルートの参照を取得できるようにしておく必要があります。

```
public void ChangeToRed(View v){
  ImageView iIcon=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.view_books_icon);
  // Fragmentの場合は、
  // ImageView iIcon=(ImageView)getView().findViewById(R.id.view_books_icon);
  iIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.red_project);
}
```